# How to find a missing element in a sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, powerbi

I have a SQL database with some data that are added daily by a third person, each person has to add 10 lines of data to one of my tables trough a form , but sometimes someone forget to add one of those lines, each line represent a different result, what i wanna do is display what line wasnt inserted in a specific day and shift, here is an example of the table

| data_id | user | date | shift | machine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3227 | 100 | 28/11/2021 | 1 | TG01 |
| 3228 | 103 | 28/11/2021 | 1 | TG02 |
| 3229 | 103 | 28/11/2021 | 1 | TG03 |
| 3230 | 100 | 28/11/2021 | 1 | TG04 |
| 3231 | 105 | 28/11/2021 | 1 | TG05 |
| 3232 | 100 | 28/11/2021 | 1 | TG06 |
| 3233 | 107 | 28/11/2021 | 1 | TG07 |
| 3234 | 100 | 28/11/2021 | 1 | TG08 |
| 3235 | 108 | 28/11/2021 | 1 | TG09 |
| 3236 | 100 | 28/11/2021 | 1 | TG010 |
| 3237 | 101 | 28/11/2021 | 2 | TG01 |
| 3238 | 101 | 28/11/2021 | 2 | TG04 |
| 3239 | 101 | 28/11/2021 | 2 | TG05 |
| 3240 | 109 | 28/11/2021 | 2 | TG06 |
| 3241 | 106 | 28/11/2021 | 2 | TG07 |
| 3242 | 101 | 28/11/2021 | 2 | TG08 |

i must have TG01, TG02, TG03 ....TG10 for every shift, how can i display in a case like in shift 2 which ones are missing?
i would like to use an sql query to display it in powerbi to not have to manually check it every day

Comment: You want a cartesian product of your dimensions ( user, date, shift, machine) minus your table.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: @Dale K im using both tags because im using mysql and sql-server with the same structure and data, mysql just for offline testing and sql-server is as main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do for this is create a simple heap table with one column going from TG01 to TG10 and do a LEFT JOIN with it checking NULL's.

The table would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE HeapTableWithMachines
(
    [machine] CHAR(4)
)
```

Then do the 10 inserts for the machines.

```
INSERT INTO HeapTableWithMachines VALUES ('TG01')
INSERT INTO HeapTableWithMachines VALUES ('TG02')
INSERT INTO HeapTableWithMachines VALUES ('TG03')
INSERT INTO HeapTableWithMachines VALUES ('TG04')
INSERT INTO HeapTableWithMachines VALUES ('TG05')
INSERT INTO HeapTableWithMachines VALUES ('TG06')
INSERT INTO HeapTableWithMachines VALUES ('TG07')
INSERT INTO HeapTableWithMachines VALUES ('TG08')
INSERT INTO HeapTableWithMachines VALUES ('TG09')
INSERT INTO HeapTableWithMachines VALUES ('TG10')
```

Then use a subselect to check a shift already inserted but missing some machines by doing a cartesian product aka CROSS JOIN and after that check against the whole table.

```
 SELECT 
           S.[user]
          ,S.[date]
          ,S.[shift]
          ,S.[machine]
      FROM (SELECT M.[machine], T0.[user], T0.[date], T0.[shift] 
                FROM [HeapTableWithMachines] M,  [TableWithLinesInsertedByThirdPerson] T0 GROUP BY M.[machine], T0.[user], T0.[date], T0.[shift]) S
      LEFT JOIN [TableWithLinesInsertedByThirdPerson] T1 ON S.[date] = T1.[date] AND S.[machine] = T1.[machine] AND S.[shift] = T1.[shift] AND S.[user] = T1.[user] WHERE T1.[user] IS NULL
```

PS: I agree with Yitzhak Khabinsky that there should more information to work with your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, im still working on it because i want to do it in a way that i can struggle to learn, your tip of creating a heap table really gave me a direction of where to go

Answer (score 0):

One would assume that your database is properly normalized, therefore you would have a `Users` table, as well as a `Shift` table. You would also have a `Machine` table containing the machines `TG01`-`TG10`.

You also need a calendar table called `Dates`, containing a row for each day. You can generate this on the fly, but it's easier with a proper table

You then cross-join them all, and remove rows where there is a match from your table

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Users u
CROSS JOIN Shift s
CROSS JOIN Machine m
JOIN Dates d ON d.Date BETWEEN '20211101' AND CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM YourTable sd
    WHERE sd.[User] = u.Id
      AND sd.Shift = s.Id
      AND sd.Machine = m.Id);
```